# Detect specific key regardless of language setting

Tags: windows, winapi

(Windows interop here)

**Background:**

ConEmu is a program I just found, very cool, allowing a lot of features for interacting with the command line. However, it has a "Quake" feature where you would hit a key and get a console dropping out of the top like in most FPS games. I found a bug where it would not work properly depending on the language setting of the user. You can check the [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/issues/detail?id=588) if you want to know about it.

**Question:**

Is there a way to hook a callback into a specific key (not character, but specific key on the keyboard), regardless of the language setting the user has?

Comment: As i wrote in issue comment, ConEmu uses RegisterHotKey for global registration.

Comment: @Maximus Thanks Maximus! (Great to see you here, BTW). If we're lucky, someone will let us know of some other method that could achieve the trick. I think the workaround described is fine but I'm still curious on if there's a way to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: For clarification. There is a key with ScanCode 0x2B, which has different VirtualKeyCodes. VK(GB)=VK_OEM_7, VK(ES)=VK_OEM_2. So, RegisterHotKey sucks... It is possible to hook this key with SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL), but I not very like this way, cause of automatic loading ConEmu libraries in foreground process.